# How do I make my application find the gettext translations?

Tags: c, gtk, locale, translation, gettext

I'm trying out gettext translations for [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org).

`gettext` generates a `po/xnec2c.pot` file at build time and I have translated that `.pot` file to de_DE and placed it in `/usr/share/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/xnec2c.po` (also tried as `.pot` and `.mo`).

If I invoke xnec2c as `LC_ALL=de_DE ./xnec2c` then I know it gets the locale because decimal points become comma's instead of periods in floating point values, but the text is not being translated.  I've tried setting `LC_MESSAGES=de_DE` as well but no change in the text language.

The `_()` macro is defined as:

```c
#define _(String) dgettext (PACKAGE, String)
```

and `autoconf` has `PACKAGE` defined as "xnec2c" in `configure.ac` which does show up properly in `config.h`.

The console output uses `vfprintf` as follows, note the use of `_(format)`:

```c
vfprintf(stderr, _(format), args);
```

and I have verified that the formatted strings to be printed exist in the translated .pot file.

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?  I've read quite a bit of gettext documentation and I'm not sure what to try next.

(The 'gtk' tag is on here because we are using a translated .glade file, too, in case that is relevant.)

Here are some samples (mechanically-translated as `de` is not my native `$LANG`):

#### xnec2c.pot

```
#: src/callback_func.c:684
msgid "View Currents"
msgstr ""

#: src/callback_func.c:810
msgid "GNUplot files (*.gplot)"
msgstr ""

#: src/callbacks.c:88 src/callbacks.c:328 src/callbacks.c:2065
msgid "Really quit xnec2c?"
msgstr ""
```

#### /usr/share/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/xnec2c.po

```
msgid "View Currents"
msgstr "Ströme anzeigen"

msgid "GNUplot files (*.gplot)"
msgstr "GNUplot-Dateien (*.gplot)"

msgid "Really quit xnec2c?"
msgstr "Wirklich verlassen xnec2c?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation file under `/usr/share/...` should be named `xnec2c.mo`, not `.po`. You mentioned having tried that already, but since you are not metioning `msgfmt` at all, did you perhaps simply rename the `.po` to `.mo`?

Renaming will not work, the file would be in the wrong format. The `.po` needs to be converted by using the command `msgfmt -vco xnec2c.mo xnec2c.po`.

(`-v` for verbose, `-c` for stricter syntax check, `-o` for output)

Comment: Pretty sure this is the issue, not understanding that .mo was binary I did just rename it.  Still pinning down the details because the .po's had quoting issues, too.

Answer (score 1):

Near the start of the program you must call something like

```
  bindtextdomain(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, LOCALEDIR);
  bind_textdomain_codeset(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, "UTF-8");
  textdomain(GETTEXT_PACKAGE);
```

where `GETTEXT_PACKAGE` and `LOCALEDIR` are macros that are usually defined by autoconf. (It seems you are using only `PACKAGE` instead of `GETTEXT_PACKAGE`, and `LOCALEDIR` is where the `.mo` files are stored.)